# Geometry in the nxn Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I recently stumbled upon the fascinating online series on linear algebra by the youtube channel 3blue1brown and have been hunting for geometrical interpretations and intuitive explanations for every single expression i had encountered in linear algebra.The n by n determinant however is not arrived at by a definition that involves geometry at all; instead it stems from a set of clearly defined properties that it alone is capable of satisfying. Is it possible to show that the formula for an n by n determinant is also the factor by which the volume equivalent in n dimensions is scaled by? if so how does one go about such a feat? and does the recursive nature of the definition have any significance or is it just a compact way of expression that is merely coincidental?

PS: if possible, please direct me to additional resources and please dont do the mathematical equivalent of pulling out a lightsaber to pick a lock and end up giving an answer that i'm incapable of neither comprehending nor accepting.

Comment: There are various possible definitions of the determinant, including being the volume scaling factor, each equivalent. Which definition do you use?

Comment: i want to define a determinant as the factor by which volume is scaled and then arrive at the same final expression as the one any other definition leads to.

Comment: Well, whichever direction you choose, you can use elementary row/column operations to proceed. I'm sure you can find several proofs on this site.